# Get folders names inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a[rel='Hotel']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"
      });
      $("a[rel='Rooms']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"
      });
   });
</script>
```

Where Hotel and Rooms are the names of the two folders I have inside in the galleries folder.

What I want to achieve to automate the creation of the folders. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a[rel='Hotel']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"});
      $("a[rel='Rooms']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"});
      $("a[rel='Another Name']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"});
      $("a[rel='Another Name']").colorbox({
         maxWidth: "90%",
         maxHeight: "90%",
         opacity: ".5"
      });
   });
</script>
```

I have tried using something like this but it didn't work

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        function listFolderFiles($dir) {
           $ffs = scandir($dir);
                   foreach($ffs as $ff){
           if ($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
           echo "$('a[rel='$ff']').colorbox({maxWidth: '90%', maxHeight: '90%', opacity: '.5'});";
        }
        }
     }

     listFolderFiles('galleries');
     });
  </script>
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Uhm, what ? Is that PHP inside javascript, or is something else going on. This is totally confusing !

Comment: is that javascript or php?

Comment: Is that PHP code? What is that `scandir` function, there is no such thing in JavaScript? And the `foreach` loop is a syntax error.

Comment: well I have tried to combine javascript with PHP :)

Comment: You cannot mix JavaScript and php inside the JavaScript tags. If you wish to combine the two. I'd recommend Ajax

Comment: @Daryl Gill, see the JS and PHP mixed version :)

Comment: @largan I stand corrected. Php will not parse correctly inside the JavaScript tags. If you look on the error console(s) you'll most likely be flooded with errors

Comment: @Daryl Gill, no errors in the console, but thanks anyway... I learned a lot from this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using pure JS then just use a for statement and pull from an array:

```
var strings = ['Hotel', 'Room'];
for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
    $("a[rel='" + strings[i] + "']").colorbox({
        maxWidth: "90%",
        maxHeight: "90%",
        opacity: ".5"
    });
}
```

### As per OP request

```
function addType(name){
    $("a[rel='" + name + "']").colorbox({
        maxWidth: "90%",
        maxHeight: "90%",
        opacity: ".5"
    });
}
```

### Edit

After having a discussion with the OP solution is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function listAdd(){ 

        <? 
        $dir = "galleries/"; 

        // Sort in ascending order - this is default 
        $folders = scandir($dir); 
        echo 'var folders = ', json_encode($folders);echo ';'; 
        ?> 

        if(folders[0] == '.') folders.shift(); 
        if(folders[0] == '..') folders.shift();
        for(var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++){ 
            $("a[rel='" + folders[i] + "']").colorbox({ 
                maxWidth: "90%", 
                maxHeight: "90%", 
                opacity: ".5" 
            }); 
        }
    }
    listAdd();
});
```

Comment: `strings.length` you mean

Comment: @wavemode Thank you, missed that.

Comment: I am trying to avoid Adding the directories names manually... I want at the moment I create new directory to auromatically create 
$("a[rel='THE NEW DIRECTORY NAME']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});

Comment: The edit allows for dynamic adding of the directory. Just call it via `addType(name)`.

Comment: @largan If it worked for you I would appreciate it if you clicked the little tick by the vote buttons. Thank you.

Comment: Ops, it seems I have rushed saying that it worked... perhaps it is working but I am not sure as I am not sure how to call it withing the $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: If the variable `name` is the name of the string you want then just type `addType(name);`.

Comment: huh, I am not very good with js... :( can your edit your post with the complete code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50977/discussion-between-lugia101101-and-largan)